# will a larger gauge wire used to extend and outlet prevent power loss

Tags: wiring

i need to get a power source 200' out from an existing outlet.  Can I use a 8 gauge wire from the existing outlet to the new one to prevent power loss?

Comment: What size breaker are you intending to use? How much current do you think you will be drawing? Will this be a 120 V circuit?

Comment: What are you trying to power here?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.  You are always allowed to upsize the wire.  You will need to **pigtail** the ends of the wires onto a smaller wire so it will fit on the terminals at both ends.

I gather you've recently visited a voltage drop calculator.  A few tricks on using those effectively:

- Use the Ampere rating of the *actual loads you will be powering*, never use the amps of the breaker trip.  In fact, if your load is more than 80% of breaker trip (16A for a 20A  breaker), that means you're overloading the circuit.  So you should never put more than 16A for a 20A circuit.
- 3% *is not gospel*.  The best practice is to limit voltage drop to 8% *from the service panel to the final load*, so you should separately add up voltage drop for each wiring segment.  Often with those calcs, if you change the number to 4%, you find that the next smaller wire would have worked at, say 3.3% (which is perfectly fine).
- Make sure you select 120V or 240V correctly.
- Distance is one-way (on most of them). It's automatically calculating for both directions of voltage drop.